# Can you legally keep(pool/collect/save) people's money to give to an organization?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer

Is it legal for me to get checks from say ten people for $300 to pay for a weekend camp, and then give the camp a check for $3000, or can only a 501(c)3 to do that?

Comment: Basically, do I need a 501c3 to do that?

Comment: "do I need a 501c3 to do that?"  I don't see why.  After all, you're **paying them for services rendered**.  Ask the camp if they'll allow it, or if they'd rather you send them the ten individual checks.

Comment: But me pooling funds for the camp is fine?

Comment: I'd sure do it if I were in your shoes, and the camp wanted a single check that I'd do it.

Comment: But this brings up another question: is this for some sort of organized group, like a school, church, Scouting, Boys & Girls Club, etc?

Comment: Yeah it is an organized group.

Comment: Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/111808/kids-pooling-money-for-lego-league-and-taxes

Comment: Thanks, I think that helped