# Why a W9 is needed for firstinspires Kids Robotics

Tags: united-states, taxes, teenager, fund-raising

Some kids(including mine) are doing [LEGO](http://www.firstinspires.org) competition and for that they received $500 ( yet to actually receive) from a corporation for their expenses( about $3K) pooled between them.

To get this $500 from the company, LEGO is asking for a [W9](https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/regranting-process-procedures-and-w-9), from an [earlier question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/111808), I understand there is no tax implications, but firstinspires is asking for  business Tax ID, and suggesting to reach to library as quoted below

> Sometimes teams are not directly associated with a school or an organization who can formally provide a W-9. We totally get that! Luckily, we have found that local organizations, such as libraries, will accept the regrant on the team’s behalf and distribute the regrant funds to the team.

How to reach to Library or any friend who has a company ?

Comment: The too-obvious-to-make-it-an-answer answer would be to go into the library and ask them if they would be prepared to act in this manner. Similarly if you know a friend who has a company.

Comment: Your title asks "Why?" but your final sentence asks "How?". Which is it? @TripleHound covered the how. Q for OP: the quoted item talks about a library or local organization (i.e. a non-profit), but you bring up a company. I think that whoever is giving your kids the money wants to give it to a non-profit or government organization, not a company.